# Receiving Error in iAd's Pre-Roll Video Ad however Ad plays

Tags: ios, swift, iad

Although the iAd Pre-Roll Video Ad plays successfully, I am receiving an error in the Pre-Roll Video Ad. I am wondering if there is an error in my code.

This is the error message:

> iAdPreRollVideoAdTest[ ... : ... ] nil

This is the code that prints the error:

```
 moviePlayer.playPrerollAdWithCompletionHandler { (error) -> Void in
            NSLog("\(error)")

            self.moviePlayer.view.removeFromSuperview()
            //I want to remove it after the ad plays
        }
```

Is there something wrong with my code? Or is this normal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is nothing wrong with your code, but there's no sense in printing `error` to the console if its value is equal to `nil`.

`nil` is essentially the absence of a valid value. So, the reason `nil` is being printed to your console is because `error` contains no value. We only want `error` printed to the console in cases where there is actually an error to print. The way we accomplish this is by checking if `error` is not equal, `!=`, to `nil`, and if it is not, we print the error to the console. For example:

```
moviePlayer.playPrerollAdWithCompletionHandler { (error) -> Void in
    if (error) != nil {
        println("\(error)")
    } 
    self.moviePlayer.view.removeFromSuperview()
}
```

Comment: Thanks again! You are always amazing!